# Problems with making ebay REST api call

Tags: rest, ebay-api

I've write following code:

```
    include('httpful.phar');
include('config.php');
use \Httpful\Request;

class fullfil_pol_data{
    public $name='1dzien';
    public $marketplace='EBAY_PL';
    public $category=array('name' => 'ALL_EXCLUDING_MOTORS_VEHICLES');
    public $czas_wysylki=array('value'=> 1, 'unit'=>'DAY');
}
class aukcja{
    public $ilosc;
    public $cat_id;
    public $format;
    public $opis;
}
class token{
    public $token;
    private $duration;
    private $starts;
    public function __construct($t, $d){
        $this->token=$t;
        $this->duration=$d;
        $this->starts=time();
    }
    public function check(){
        if($this->duration+$this->starts >= time()-15*60) ibej::get_token();
    }
}
class ibej{
    private $token;
    private $sandbox=true;
    public function get_token()
    {
        if(this->sandbox) $url='https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token';
        $req= Request::post($url)->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                                        ->addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '.PASSES)
                                        ->body("grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=Marketing_Desig-Marketin-wystaw-blzyg&scope=https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope")->send();
        $this->token = new token($req->body->access_token, $req->body->expires_in);
        var_dump($this->token);
    }

    /*$url='https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/offer';
    //$req= Request::post($url)->addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$token)
        //                          ->addHeader('X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID', 'EBAY-PL')
        */
    public function post_fullfilment_policy()
    {
        if(this->sandbox) $url='https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/sell/account/v1/fulfillment_policy';
        $test= new fullfil_pol_data;
        $req= Request::post($url)->addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$this->token->token)
                                ->addHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
                                ->addheader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                ->addHeader('X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID', 'EBAY-US')
                                ->body(json_encode($test))->send();
        var_dump($req);
    }
}
$ibej_api = new ibej;
$ibej_api->get_token();
$ibej_api->post_fullfilment_policy();
```

When I try to call fullfilmentpolicy (http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/rest/api-ref/account/fulfillment_policy__post.html) with ->post_fullfilment_policy() method I've this error in response:

*"{"errors":[{"errorId":1100,"domain":"ACCESS","category":"REQUEST","message":"Access denied","longMessage":"Insufficient permissions to fulfill the request."}]}"*

I don't know what is wrong, I reckon that If I have obtained token, it should give me permissions to do things with my account. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have created an [Application token](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-gen-app-token.html). In order to perform API operations on eBay that involve a seller's account you have to create a User Token.This is explained in the [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-gen-user-token.html). Note that the process involved in getting a user token requires the user to log into their eBay account to grant permission to your application. The process is very different to obtaining an application token.

Comment: It's a mess! It's impossible to have an autonomus app that post item on my ebay store!!!